# Find out the miss classify image when using the keras model as a image classifier

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I built a keras model for image classification in the data set there are 5 class but when model classify the image i found around 200 images are not classify can any one help me how can i find out those images that are not classify.This is my model

```
    img_width= img_rows
    img_height = img_cols
    classes_num = 5
    epochs = 10

    model =Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(classes_num ))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
                            metrics=['accuracy',mean_pred,recall,precision, fmeasure,
                                     matthews_correlation,kullback_leibler_divergence,
                                     binary_crossentropy])
    model.save('model.h5')
    model.summary()
    print('model complied!!')

    print('starting training....')
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=64,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

'''

Comment: Are your images wrongly classified or are they not classified at all? Without more information (code) it is hard to help you.

Comment: I think it would be better if you upload your code here.

Comment: I add the model is this help me to find out the miss classify image